# Android:Pairing of 2 bluetooth devices in android automatically in programatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

Currently am working for Bluetooth.I stuck at pairing Bluetooth automatically with out user interface.

let me explain clearly where am getting stuck::I'm trying to programmatically pair a bluetooth device. I'm able to show the pairing dialog for the device I want to pair and If I press Ok on the dialog then its able to connect. but I don't want user interface to click ok button.is there any way to connect automatically?

Thanks in advance

the following code is using for pairing::

```
BroadcastReceiver mDiscoveredDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Logc.d(TAG, "Action::" + action);
            try {
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String value = device.getName();
                    String address = device.getAddress();
                    Logc.d(TAG, "Address::" + address + "::value:" + value);
                    if (address.equals(mAddress) && value.equals(mName)) {

                        Logc.d(TAG, "Found the pairing device Bluetooth Address");


                       Method m = device.getClass()
                               .getDeclaredMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null); // I use createInsecureRfcommSocket, still unable to pair automatically
                                m.invoke(device,Integer.valueOf(1) );



                    }
                    context.unregisterReceiver(mDiscoveredDevicesReceiver);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Logc.d(TAG, "Found Exception is::" + e.toString());
            }
        }




    };
```

Comment: In both the device, you are running your program?

Comment: hi patro,   no..on one device (from which device we are doing  pairing )only am running the program.